# Create a List of Tuple from 3 Lists

Tags: c#

I have 3 variables of type `IEnumerable<Decimal?`>: `a`, `b` and `c`.

How can I create a `IEnumerable<Tuple<Decimal?, Decimal?, Decimal?>` where the Tuple's items are `a`, `b` and `c`?

Using the following creates 3 lists and not a list of tuple:

```
(a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-5.0):

```
IEnumerable<(Decimal? a, Decimal? b, Decimal? c)> list 
    = a.Zip(b, (a, b) => (a, b)).Zip(c, (ab, c) => (ab.a, ab.b, c));
```

now you can access each decimal with it's name:

```
foreach(var abc in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine("a: " + abc.a);
    Console.WriteLine("b: " + abc.b);
    Console.WriteLine("c: " + abc.c);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me is more natural this:

```
var list = a.Zip(b).Zip(c).Select(nt => (nt.First.First, nt.First.Second, nt.Second))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well assuming all lists are always the same size, you could create a new list of Tuple(a,b,c), and fill it with the respective values, by iterating and creating new tuple instances each time like so:

```
var myTupleEnumerable = new List<Tuple<decimal?, decimal?, decimal?>>();
for(int i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
{
  myTupleEnumerable.Add(new Tuple<decimal?, decimal?, decimal?>(itemA[i], itemB[i], itemC[i]));
}
```

Comment: the (decimal) values from the corresponding lists

Comment: The Items from the lists need to be accessed with the iterator like `[i]`, i missed that earlier